# fbthrift: No generator named 'cpp2' could be found after (seemingly) successful build

Tags: lua, thrift, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to install [crnn](https://github.com/bgshih/crnn) which requires [fblualib](https://github.com/facebookarchive/fblualib) on **Ubuntu 18.04 LTS**. While building [TH++](https://github.com/facebook/thpp), an error occured (Complete build print attached below):

```
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/thpp.dir/Storage.cpp.o
In file included from /home/huiji/Downloads/thpp-master/thpp/Storage.cpp:11:0:
/home/huiji/Downloads/thpp-master/thpp/../thpp/Storage.h:22:10: fatal error: thpp/if/gen-cpp2/Tensor_types.h: no such file or directory
 #include **<thpp/if/gen-cpp2/Tensor_types.h>**
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

If I build thpp without using fbthrift and folly by running `THPP_NOFB=1 ./build.sh` in the thpp directory, the build would be successful (I have thpp files in torch/install/include and torch/install/lib). However, if I move on and build fblualib, an almost identical error occurs:

```
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fblualib.dir/LuaUtils.cpp.o
In file included from 
/home/huiji/torch/install/include/thpp/Tensor.h:20:0,
                 from /home/huiji/Downloads/fblualib-master/fblualib/../fblualib/LuaUtils.h:19,
                 from /home/huiji/Downloads/fblualib- master/fblualib/LuaUtils.cpp:11:
/home/huiji/torch/install/include/thpp/Storage.h:22:10: fatal error: 
thpp/if/gen-cpp2/Tensor_types.h: no such file or directory
 #include <thpp/if/gen-cpp2/Tensor_types.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I figure that there may be something wrong with my [fbthrift](https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift). Then I tried the following commands under directory "thpp/if/". It seems that my fbthrift can't generate a cpp2-format file, but can generate a cpp/py file, awhile my python thrift_compiler can only generate an errored cpp2-format file.

```
$ thrift --gen cpp2 Tensor.thrift 
  [WARNING:/home/huiji/Downloads/thpp-master/thpp/if/Tensor.thrift:1] No generator named 'cpp2' could be found!
  [WARNING:generation:1] Unable to get a generator for "cpp2".
  # Nothing was generated in /thpp/if

$ thrift --gen cpp Tensor.thrift && ls gen-cpp
  [WARNING:/home/huiji/Downloads/thpp-master/thpp/if/Tensor.thrift:3] No generator named 'cpp2' could be found!
  Tensor_constants.cpp  Tensor_constants.h  Tensor_types.cpp  Tensor_types.h

$ thrift --gen py Tensor.thrift && ls -R gen-py
  [WARNING:/home/huiji/Downloads/thpp-master/thpp/if/Tensor.thrift:3] No generator named 'cpp2' could be found!
  gen-py:
  __init__.py  Tensor
  gen-py/Tensor:
  constants.py  __init__.py  ttypes.py

$ python -m thrift_compiler.main --gen cpp2 Tensor.thrift && ls gen-cpp2
  Tensor_fatal_all.h       Tensor_fatal.h          Tensor_fatal_types.h
  Tensor_fatal_constant.h  Tensor_fatal_service.h  Tensor_fatal_union.h
  Tensor_fatal_enum.h      Tensor_fatal_struct.h
  # A "gen-cpp2" directory was created, but in it there was no "Tensor_types.h"!

$ python -m thrift_compiler.main --gen cpp Tensor.thrift
  ('Argument Error:', ArgumentError('Language cpp not defined.',))

$ python -m thrift_compiler.main --gen py Tensor.thrift
```

('Argument Error:', ArgumentError('Language py not defined.',))

By the way, my fbthrift install seemed successful except the python package thrift_compiler was not installed correctly. I've followed [GitHubGS's suggestion](https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift/issues/249#issuecomment-368206653). That seem to have worked (I can now import thrift_compiler in python, below is what I did) but as you can see, it is not really working.

> 1.modify /thrift/compiler/CMakefile.txt by inserting these lines
>
> set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "-fPIC")
> set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-fPIC")
>
> 2.rebuild/reinstall fbthrift(must step)
>
> 3.run your command under /fbthrift/thrift/compiler/py
>
> g++ -I /usr/include/python2.7 -I ../../.. -std=c++14 -fpic -shared -o frontend.so compiler.cc -lboost_python -lpython2.7 -L/build/lib -lcompiler_base -lcompiler_ast -lboost_system -lboost_filesystem -lssl -lcrypto
>
> sudo cp frontend.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thrift_py-0.9.0-py2.7.egg/thrift_compiler

Any ideas/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

=================

Complete message of **thpp** build:

```
huiji@NoBoDy:~/Downloads/thpp-master/thpp$ ./build.sh
If you don't have folly or thrift installed, try doing
  THPP_NOFB=1 ./build.sh
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Torch7 in /home/huiji/torch/install
-- Found Folly: /usr/local/include
-- Found Thrift: /usr/local/include
-- Performing Test HAS_NO_AS_NEEDED
-- Performing Test HAS_NO_AS_NEEDED - Success
-- Found Glog: /usr/include
-- Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.15")
-- Looking for pthread.h
-- Looking for pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthreads - not found
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread
-- Looking for pthread_create in pthread - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/huiji/Downloads/thpp-master/thpp/build
[  5%] Generating thpp/if/gen-cpp2/Tensor_data.h, thpp/if/gen-cpp2/Tensor_types.h, thpp/if/gen-cpp2/Tensor_types.tcc, thpp/if/gen-cpp2/Tensor_constants.h, thpp/if/gen-cpp2/Tensor_data.cpp, thpp/if/gen-cpp2/Tensor_types.cpp, thpp/if/gen-cpp2/Tensor_constants.cpp
Scanning dependencies of target thpp
[ 10%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/thpp.dir/Storage.cpp.o
In file included from /home/huiji/Downloads/thpp-master/thpp/Storage.cpp:11:0:
/home/huiji/Downloads/thpp-master/thpp/../thpp/Storage.h:22:10: fatal error: thpp/if/gen-cpp2/Tensor_types.h: no such file or directory
 #include <thpp/if/gen-cpp2/Tensor_types.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/thpp.dir/build.make:84: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/thpp.dir/Storage.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/thpp.dir/Storage.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/thpp.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/thpp.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:140: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Complete message of **fblualib** build:

```
huiji@NoBoDy:~/Downloads/fblualib-master/fblualib$ ./build.sh
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.3.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/gcc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/local/bin/gcc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/g++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/local/bin/g++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Folly: /usr/local/include
-- Found Glog: /usr/include
-- Found Torch7 in /home/huiji/torch/install
-- Found Folly: /home/huiji/torch/install/include
-- Configuring done
WARNING: Target "fblualib" requests linking to directory "/home/huiji/torch/install/lib".  Targets may link only to libraries.  CMake is dropping the item.
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/huiji/Downloads/fblualib-master/fblualib/build
Scanning dependencies of target fblualib
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/fblualib.dir/LuaUtils.cpp.o
In file included from /home/huiji/torch/install/include/thpp/Tensor.h:20:0,
                 from /home/huiji/Downloads/fblualib-master/fblualib/../fblualib/LuaUtils.h:19,
                 from /home/huiji/Downloads/fblualib-master/fblualib/LuaUtils.cpp:11:
/home/huiji/torch/install/include/thpp/Storage.h:22:10: fatal error: thpp/if/gen-cpp2/Tensor_types.h: no such file or directory
 #include <thpp/if/gen-cpp2/Tensor_types.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
CMakeFiles/fblualib.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/fblualib.dir/LuaUtils.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/fblualib.dir/LuaUtils.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/fblualib.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/fblualib.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:129: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `thrift1` and `mstch_cpp2` instead. It works for me!

See https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift/issues/271 and `$THRIFT_INCLUDE` is `/usr/local/include/thrift/` in my system.

Answer (score 0):

As one of the above answer mentioned, after building fbthrift successfully, you get `bin/thrift1` binary in your build folder. You can then use the output `thrift1` with generator `mstch_cpp2`.

```sh
./build/bin/thrift1 --gen mstch_cpp2 --templates ./thrift/compiler/generate/templates --out /tmp/ ./thrift/example/if/chatroom.thrift
```

Ref https://github.com/facebook/fbthrift/issues/303